# letting the a group of users to be owner of SiteCollection....?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is the quoted question below is possible in sharepoint, if yes, please suggest some solution too. I will be grateful.

**"Can we let a group of users to make their own site collections, and then to make them the owners of their own site collections. Mind you, other users in a group should not be able to access each others site collections. Unless, they are given permission by the sitecollection owner."**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To do this for sites (not site collections)

- create a custom group with the create
  site permissions
- Add the users to the
  group
- when they create a site, they
  will be the owner of the site and can
  assign permissions to that site (only
  if they check the "Use Unique
  Permissions") when creating the site
  collection.

I am pretty sure you can do the same for site collections, however you would do that through central admin rather than the top level site itself.

Comment: Hi, I have another question please. Is it possible to customize the page to enable the "use Unique permission" radio button checked and disable it?